# Autoloading language in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am newbie in CodeIgniter, so I need help of professionals.
I am making multilanguage website. I know that CodeIgniter has support of this, but I have a problem:

For some reasons, namely I do not want to load language in every controller that I create, I create my own library, put it as shown in documentation in `application/library`and add it to autoload configuration file:

```
class Langload {

public function __construct()
{
    $ci =& get_instance();

    $lang_id = $ci->session->userdata('userlang');

    switch($lang_id){
        case "ru":
            $userLang = "russian";
            break;
        case "en":
            $userLang = "english";
            break;
        default:
            $userLang = "english";  
    }


    if(!$ci->lang->load('main', $userLang)){

        echo "LANG ERROR";
    }    
}

public function get_lang_link(){
    $ci =& get_instance();

    $lang_id = $ci->session->userdata('userlang');
    switch($lang_id) {
        case "ru":
            $lang_link = "<li><a href=\"/lng/en\">Switch to English</a></li>";
        break;
        case "en":
            $lang_link = "<li><a href=\"/lng/ru\">Переключиться на Русский</a></li>";
        break;
    }

    return $lang_link;
}
```

}

?>

So as result I get error "LANG ERROR" and language doesn't loading, and I still have language, that I put in config default language `$config['language']   = 'russian';`

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: what is the name of your language file?

Answer (score 1):

So I have solved problem when I remove language from autoload.